# Git pre-commit hook errors while executing another script

Tags: git, groovy, hook, smartgit, pre-commit

I have written git pre-commit hook using groovy script. I am using Windows 7. Since the files located at

> `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

are not version controlled, I have moved these pre-commit hooks to project sub-repository.

> `${PROJECT_REPO}/git-hooks` directory.

This is the script in file @ `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
public class PreCommitHooks
{
    public static boolean CheckBannedFilesToCommit() 
    {
        def process = "cmd /c groovy ../../git-hooks/pre-commit".execute();
        process.waitFor();
        if (process.exitValue())
        { 
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

// Create an instance of PreCommitHooks() class and execute list of hooks.
preCommitHook = new PreCommitHooks();
if (!preCommitHook.CheckBannedFilesToCommit())
{
    System.exit(1);
}
else
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Script in file @ `git-hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

This is pseudo code only 
process all the hook info.
.... 
if (!bSuccess)
    system.exit(1);
else
    system.exit(0);
```

I have installed all the `${GROOVY_HOME}` and `${JAVA_HOME}` paths correctly, verified using windows command line. My scripts run perfectly when called  using Windows Command line.

```
${PROJECT_REPO}/.git/hooks>groovy pre-commit
```

Since all the scripts are working, I proceeded to test my pre-commit hook using [smart-git](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/)

File @ `.git/hooks/pre-commit` gets executed properly, it is able to find `${GROOVY_HOME}` and `${JAVA_HOME}` paths properly. But when executing following line

```
def process = "cmd /c groovy ../../git-hooks/pre-commit".execute();
```

It fails with following error.

> Error: JAVA_HOME is set to invalid directory: 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Jdk1.8.0_51
>   Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of 
>   your Java installation.

Can anyone please help me resolve this error?

I am looking for a groovy script solution instead of bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using windows symlink instead.

```
cmd /c mklink /H ${link_file_full_path} ${Target_file_full_path}
```

Calling a groovy script (located at `$WORK_TREE`} from another groovy script located at `$GIT_DIR` did not work.

I believe it must be to do with environment variables. Smartgit passes all the environment variables to first script and that information is lost when another script is called.